# Recover Pages Password

Tags: macos, terminal, password, keychain, pages

I locked a pages document and forgot the password. I tried looking up on keychain and it doesn't show up there

I've been through a lot of posts on discussions.apple.com (basically did a google search and opened every article until i was tired), including this one where the comment mentions a way through terminal :

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4537649?answerId=20382428022#20382428022

Does anyone know a method to crack or bypass or locate a copy of my password for this file?